# Install a github repository as a library through a script file

Tags: github, arduino

I am trying to remove the libraries folder in an Arduino project I am working on and install them through a script file. The issue with some of the libraries is that they seem to not be officially registered, so you can't use the arduino-cli lib install for them. Most of them are on github, so I am looking for a way to install them in a similar fashion as arduino-cli lib install, so they can all be neatly in one script file. I am slightly new to github and I am not sure if there is a way through which this is achievable.

Comment: You can follow the instructions on https://www.arduino.cc/en/guide/libraries#toc4 or https://www.arduino.cc/en/guide/libraries#toc5

Comment: Thank you for your response. Both links revolve around using a libraries folder to hold the selected libraries, which was done previously and I am trying to 'undo' by installing them through a script so that they do not have to be held in a local libraries folder.

Comment: use `git` command line tool

Comment: Could you specify a bit @Juraj? I've read through a bunch of documentation, and I believe I am trying to achieve something like a git clone but to have the 'clone' in the background, where you cannot see or edit it. I am not sure if git clone is the right tool for this, but it was the closest connection I could find.